# RE: Reflectivity/transmission of circularly polarised light?

Tags: visible-light, reflection

So, the Fresnel equations describe nicely the reflectance or transmission of s or p polarised light.

What happens in the case of circularly polarised light? When thinking about a propogation through air into a dielectric is it best to image that the circularly polarised light is a combination s and p amplitudes?

Is there a Fresnel equation for circularly polarised light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For optically isotropic substances (so cubic crystals and amorphous materials like glass) there is no mixing of $s$ and $p$ polarization at an interface. Then one is justified to decompose the incident light in *senkrecht* (= perpendicular) and *parallel* to the plane of reflection. For circularly and for unpolarized light this is 50 % each. Calculate the reflected intensity separately for each polarization. Then add these intensities.

This is not correct when $s$ and $p$ light are mixed by birefringent thin films or substrates, or even lower symmetries. Then one needs the complete machinery of elllipsometry.

Comment: This gives you only the intensities of the reflected and transmitted linear p- and s-wave components of the circularly polarized wave. You will not get the polarizations of the reflected and transmitted wave. Thus you will not obtain the generally resulting elliptical wave polarizations, or equivalently, the intensities of the reflected and transmitted  right and left circularly polarized waves. To get that, you have to use the Fresnel equations for the complex amplitudes not the Fresnel equations for intensities.

Comment: @freecharly That was obvious, was not it? But a straightforward way of calculating reflected intensity seems what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I am sure that you know the problems of reflection/transmission of EM waves very well. I only had  the impression that the OP was looking for Fresnel equations that give the reflection/transmission for circularly polarized waves, which don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the symmetries of the scattering problem that determines the Fresnel coefficients, one can see that $s$-polarization would remain $s$-polarization and $p$-polarization would remain $p$-polarization. In other words, the linear states of polarization that are parallel and perpendicular to the plane of reflection are the eigenstates of the process. This is not true for the circular states of polarization. If one comes in with right-circular polarization, the transmitted and reflected light will be superpositions of right- and left-circular states of polarization. The same happens when one comes in with left-circular polarization. As a result, one does not get Fresnel coefficients for circular polarization that look as nicely as they do for $s$- and $p$-polarization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how can I go about deriving the Fresnel equation for circular polarisation cases?

Comment: @lmsavk For general interfaces there is the full machinery of ellipsometry. For a simple interface, you could decompose in $s$ and $p$, calculate and sum the intensities.

Comment: @Pieter So, for circular polarisation, intensity is the arithmetic sum of the s and p polarisation cases as a function of incidence angle?

Comment: @lmsavk Yes, for optically isotropic substances (so glass and cubic crystals). Then there is no mixing of $s$ and $p$ polarization at an interface. Then the arithmetic sum of $s$ and $p$ gives the correct answer.

Comment: @Pieter This cannot be the case. This would lead to absorption coefficients greater than 1. Can you offer more advice? Do transmission and reflectivity coefficients not need to be 0 <= x <= 1?

Comment: @lmsavk I do not see the problem. Decompose the incident light in $s$ and in $p$.  For circularly and for unpolarized light this is 50 % each. Calculate the reflected intensity for each polarization. Then add these intensities. I do not see how this could be larger than 1.

Comment: @Pieter Ahhh... That's much better, I was missing the 50% part. If you make this an answer then I'll correct it, up to you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Fresnel equations specifically for circularly polarized light. But the Fresnel equations for the s- and p-amplitude reflection and transmission factors (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations)) can be used for any polarization of the incident light. A light wave of arbitrary (elliptical) polarization can be decomposed into its (complex) s- and p-amplitudes. In particular, a circularly polarized wave consists of equal s- and p-amplitudes that have a relative phase shift of $\pi/2$. Thus you determine the s- and p-amplitudes and use the Fresnel equations and you will get the reflected and transmitted amplitudes. The reflected and and transmitted light will, in general, be elliptically polarized.