# Complex reflection coefficient for a radio frequency wave

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, radio-frequency

With an RF transmitter at location $P_1$ and a receiver at $P_2$, I would like to calculate how much power reaches $P_2$ via a reflection at a point $P_3$. Hence I need to know the reflection coefficient at $P_3$ for which I use the Fresnel equations. With the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations#Complex_amplitude_reflection_and_transmission_coefficients), I arrive at:

$$
r_p = \frac{\epsilon_2 \cos\theta_i - \sqrt{\epsilon_2 - \sin^2\theta_i}}{\epsilon_2 \cos\theta_i + \sqrt{\epsilon_2 - \sin^2\theta_i}} , \\
r_s = \frac{\cos\theta_i - \sqrt{\epsilon_2 - \sin^2\theta_i}}{\cos\theta_i + \sqrt{\epsilon_2 - \sin^2\theta_i}} ,
$$

where I assume an electromagnetic wave travels through free space ($n_1=1$ or $\mu_r=\epsilon_r=1$) and is reflected at a non-magnetic ($\mu_r=1$) second medium $n_2=Z_0/Z_2=\sqrt{\epsilon_2}$ with relativ dielectric constant $\epsilon_2$, which is generally complex-valued. For a concrete wall, it is given as $\epsilon_2=7.9 + i0.89$ at 900 MHz [[1]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10776-015-0278-8.pdf).

Now I plot $|r_p|$, $|r_s|$ and $|(r_s+r_p)/2|$ for $-\pi/2 < \theta_i < \pi/2$:

[image]

Both horizonal and vertical polarization have a magnitude of approximately 0.5 at $\theta=0$. This means only half of the wave is reflected. Where does the other half go? Refraction?

Finally, a circularly polarized EM wave can be represented via $|(r_s+r_p)/2|$. As can be seen the reflection coefficient is zero at $\theta=0$. How can that be? That would imply a circularly polarized wave is never reflected which obviously must be wrong.

Furthermore, [[1]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10776-015-0278-8.pdf) claims the reflection would be:

$$
\Gamma_s = \frac{\epsilon_2 \sin\theta_i - \sqrt{\epsilon_2 - \cos^2\theta_i}}{\epsilon_2 \sin\theta_i + \sqrt{\epsilon_2 - \cos^2\theta_i}} .
$$

The sine and cosine are exactly swapped. Is this a mistake in [[1]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10776-015-0278-8.pdf) or are these two somehow equivalent?

Comment: for $r_p$ it should be $|\theta_i| < \pi/2$ because the angle is measured from the normal, for $\Gamma$ the angle is measured from the tangent plane : $sin(\alpha) = cos(\pi/2-\alpha)$. Also, I am not sure if the formula is correct for complex permittivity, and even if it is correct you will have to deal with the square root of a complex number and select the correct branch.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful! I adjusted my question (and added the question about circularly polarized wave).

Comment: Also good point wrt the complex permittivity which is given as $\epsilon_2 = \epsilon_2' + i\frac{\sigma}{\omega}$. So the higher the frequency, the more real-valued it comes. I plugged in some numbers and the imaginary part barely has an effect at RF frequencies.  A discrepancy is only visible for low frequencies. Regardless, any discussion of the complex permittivity would be appreciated as well.

Comment: I think the Fresnel formula holds for complex $\epsilon$, you just have to be careful with the selection of the two branches. Maybe @JanLalinsky can also help you out here.

Comment: When a circular polarized wave hits the wall in oblique incidence you should decompose the wave into the sum of two orthogonal linear polarized waves that are in quadrature phase and then apply the Fresnel formulas separately to each. Try it!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. For $\epsilon_2=9$, I get $r_p=0.5, r_s=-0.5$. As I wrote, according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations#Power_(intensity)_reflection_and_transmission_coefficients): "*so that the effective reflectivity of the material is just the average of the two reflectivities*". But as I wrote $|r_s+r_p|/2=0$ which suggests that nothing is reflected in this case but this does not make sense to me.

Comment: Also, this questions seems give the same answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/385902/re-reflectivity-transmission-of-circularly-polarised-light . So, **what** exactly am I doing wrong? EDIT: Is $(|r_s|+|r_p|)/2$ the right thing instead of $|(r_s+r_p)/2|$? Why?

Comment: I have no idea what this "average" reflectivity means but note that "unpolarized light" is not circular polarized but rather randomly polarized. So I am guessing, the formula represents some sort of average of the reflected intensities in the two polarizations, therefore the formula probably involves magnitudes.

Comment: A [complex refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Complex_refractive_index) happens when the material absorbs some of the light that propagates through it; this is (part of) the answer to your question of what happens to the rest of the wave.

Comment: As for the rest -- where did you get $(r_s+r_p)/2$ as the reflection coefficient for CP radiation?